# Why does this return an "Undefined Index" error?

Tags: php, session

The following code produces an Undefined Index error:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sessionName'])); { echo $_SESSION['sessionName']; }
```

But this works perfectly fine:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sessionName'])) echo $_SESSION['sessionName'];
```

Both check to see IF there is a `$_SESSION` set, then if TRUE show/echo that `$_SESSION` value.
I generally use curly braces but do not see or understand the error in the first case.
My IDE (PHPStorm) does not complain on syntax, so I am lost on what could be the problem.

Comment: there's a ninja `;` hiding in the first line! that's terminating the if statement, the following echo fires whether or not the index exists.

Comment: The semi-colon ends a statement, [per the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php): *"As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be **terminated with a semicolon** at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present."*

Comment: After revisiting the question, I noticed there is a vote to close as a typographical error. This isn't one. This is about behavior when introducing a semi-colon in a conditional statement and the OP wanted to know why that was. IMHO, the vote should be removed; the question should not be closed based on someone else's opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59239687/why-does-this-return-an-undefined-index-error/59239776#comment104690789_59239687) to an answer with additional information.

> The semi-colon ends a statement, [per the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php): *"As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be **terminated with a semicolon** at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present."*

What is happening here is that the first line you showed us, produces an error because the `isset()` is cancelled out/halted because of the semi-colon, and then you are trying to echo a session array that isn't set/not empty.

You also may not have started the session; that is unknown at the present time.